# How to set bitmap in center in kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, bitmap

How i can set bitmap image in center it is not in center .Here is my code and screen.I tried so much but I failed to solves this

```
fun onDraw(c: Canvas, rectF: RectF, pos: Int) {
    val p = Paint()
    p.color = color
    c.drawRect(rectF, p)

    p.color = Color.WHITE
    p.textSize - textSize.toFloat()

    var r = Rect()
    val cHeight = rectF.height()
    val cWidth = rectF.width()
    p.textAlign = Paint.Align.RIGHT
    p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, r)

    var x = 0f
    var y = 0f
    if (imageResId == 0) {

        x = cWidth / 2f - r.width() / 2f - r.left.toFloat()
        y = cHeight / 2f + r.height() / 2f - r.bottom.toFloat()
        c.drawText(text, rectF.left + x, rectF.top + y, p)

    } else {
        val d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageResId)
        val bitmap = drawableToBitmap(d!!)
        c.drawBitmap(
            bitmap,
            (rectF.left + rectF.right) / 2,
            (rectF.top + rectF.bottom) / 2,
            p
        )

    }

    clickRegion = rectF
    this.pos = pos
}
```

Here is image link that is produce error 
[enter link description here](https://prnt.sc/sfa68o)

```
 private fun drawableToBitmap(d: Drawable?): Bitmap {

    if (d is BitmapDrawable) return d.bitmap
    val bitmap =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(d!!.intrinsicWidth, d.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    var canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    d.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    d.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that your drawables are all in center  and draw from there, all you do are right, you just only need a simply offset with:

**Subtract** the **half of** the drawable's **width & height** from the **`start position`**

***Red*** to ***Green***

[image]

***Code Snippet***

```
    c.drawBitmap(
        bitmap,
        (rectF.left + rectF.right) / 2,
        (rectF.top + rectF.bottom) / 2,
        p
    )
```

To

```
    c.drawBitmap(
        bitmap,
        (rectF.left + rectF.right - bitmap.width) / 2,
        (rectF.top + rectF.bottom - bitmap.height) / 2,
        p
    )
```